# How to pass value into href link of a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to clear the values of a certain table so I want to get the table name using Bootstrap modal. I want the name of the table in url.

This is my code: 
Here I'm sending the name of the table into the modal

```
<ol class="breadcrumb text-center">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product1">Insert1</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product2">Insert2</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product3">Insert3</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product4">Insert4</a>
</ol>
```

I want to pass the value inside data-table into href as **clear.php?clear_id="table_name"**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="scrapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Confirm Clear?</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Are you sure you want to clear scrap for this table.</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="clear.php?clear_id=">Clear</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following lines of code inside your script tag and this should work fine.

```
$('#scrapModal .btn-danger').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert(e.target.pathname + e.target.search)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically change the `href` value of the Clear button in your modal by utilising the `shown.bs.modal` event trigger and building the URL with the `data-table` attribute at your disposal provided by the `relatedTarget` property in the event object.

I've add a clear button click event to emphasise this visually.

```js
$('#scrapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var table = $(e.relatedTarget).data('table')
  var href = 'clear.php?clear_id=' + table
  $('.btn-danger', this).attr('href', href)
  console.log(href)
})

// Simulate "clear" button click to alert href value
$('#scrapModal .btn-danger').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert(e.target.pathname + e.target.search)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ol class="breadcrumb text-center">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product1">Insert1</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product2">Insert2</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product3">Insert3</a>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#scrapModal" data-toggle="modal" data-table="product4">Insert4</a>
  </li>
</ol>

<div class="modal fade" id="scrapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Confirm Clear?</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&#215;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Are you sure you want to clear scrap for this table.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Clear</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a simple script like this:

```
$('#scrapModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var table = $(event.relatedTarget).data('table');
  $(this).find('.btn-danger').attr("href", "clear.php?clear_id=" + table);
)}
```

This will run when the modal appears. It would be better to give the confirm button an id attribute in order to look up in a more elegant way.

You can find more information about varying the modal content here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content